# Issue with cannot be converted to char[][] by method invocation conversion

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my method that takes the total from the openCheckHorizontal,openCheckVertical, openCheckDiagonal methods which all return integers.

```
    public static void printRecord(char[][]data, int[][]record ){
    int horizontal=0;
    int vertical=0;
    int diagonal=0;
    int total=0; 
     for(int row=0; row<data.length;row++){
       for(int col=0; col<data[row].length;col++){
      ***horizontal = openCheckHorizontal(data[row][col]);
      ***vertical=openCheckVertical(data[row][col]);
      ***diagonal=openCheckDiagonal(data[row][col]);
      total = horizontal+vertical+diagonal; 
      record[row][col]=total; 
    }//end of second loop 
}//end of first loop 
for(int row =0; row<record.length; row++){
  for(int col=0; col<record[row].length;col++){
        System.out.print(record[row][col]); 
    }//end of second loop 
    System.out.println(); 
   }//end of first loop 
  }//end of record method
```

The error I am getting is this:

**actual argument char cannot be converted to char[ ][ ] by method invocation conversion** for the lines marked with the stars. I cannot figure out why this is. I thought since the methods I invoked return integers I can store them as integers and call it back using my array.

The parameters that the three methods take are: char[ ][ ] myArray

If anyone could help me out that would be great!

Comment: What are the method signatures for the method being called? Do they take a `char` or a `char[][]`?

Comment: `data[row][col]` is a `char`, not a `char[][]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be passing the value of that array position which would be a `char`. Try changing the signatures on the three methods you are calling to take `char` as a parameter. OR if you meant to pass in the whole array you should be able to just pass `data` instead of the position `data[row][col]`

Comment: I need to count the number of chars around each value of the data array thats why I have it set to char[ ][ ] since it is an array full of char values

Comment: If i change the parameters of the methods then I wont be able to count the number of chars around each value. I am just a bit confused

Comment: if you want to pass in the whole array wouldn't you just pass in 'data' and not the specified position. 'data[row][col]' represents the one position in the array no?

Comment: `horizontal = openCheckHorizontal(data);
vertical = openCheckVertical(data);
diagonal = openCheckDiagonal(data);`